# javax.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery: when with / when without resultClass

Tags: java, jpa

- `javax.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery(String qlString)`
- `javax.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery(String qlString, Class<ResultType> resultClass)`

In which cases the `qlString` is sufficent and in which cases I also need to add the `resultClass`?

And: what part does the type of the result play in this regard (`List<ResultType> result = q.getResultList()`) ?

Comment: Care to mention which JPA documentation you have read? because such a thing should be well covered ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`javax.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery(String qlString)` returns a `Query`, while `javax.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery(String qlString, Class<ResultType> resultClass)` returns a `TypedQuery<ResultType>`.

You can use both to retrieve results, however the `Query` class will return non-generic `Object` instances or a `List`, while the `TypedQuery<ResultType>` would return `ResultType` instances or a `List<ResultType>`.

Comment: Thank you - what I don't understand in this regard - when you look at the Hibernate doc (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html), you find examples like this: `List<Account> accounts = entityManager.createQuery( "select a from Account a" ).getResultList()`. In this case the `resultClass` is not specified - and nevertheless the outcome is not `List<Object>` but `List<Account>`.

Comment: @olivmir I think you must have misread the doc, I can't find a single example where they get a typed result after calling `createQuery` without a class. They do call it this way in multiple instances, but only when they don't care about the result type, either because it's an update/create or because it's not relevant to the example.

Comment: @Aaron  There are at least three on that page.  Examples 257, 263, and 265.  I searched for "select a from Account a" and found those three (of the eight examples matching that pattern).  This of course may be a bug in the docs.

Comment: @mdfst13 Yeah, looks like I had been lazy searching. [This Hibernate doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1093) supports that it must be a bug of the docs.

Answer (score 1):

The result class is used to auto cast your result to the given type.  If you don’t specify it, the result is a list of object arrays.  `List<Object[]>`

In Java, it is not usualy possible to cast from one generic type to another, so always use the version with the type, as the following code will be clearer, typesafe, and will not require casting.

If you only select specific fields in you query, and not a single field or entity, you do not need to specify it because the default `List<Object[]>`is returned.